# Count occurrences of overlapping words between txt files

Tags: python, count, nlp, frequency

So I'm attempting to write code that compares two lists (firstfile from firstfile.txt; secondfile from secondfile.txt) and prints the number of times overlapping words from firstfile appear in secondfile.

So, for example, if in firstfile(.txt) I have:

```
'beautiful', 'day', 'neighborhood', 'sun'
```

and in secondfile(.txt) I have

```
"It's a beautiful day in the neighborhood today. The sun is shining brightly, and the birds are singing. 
And now I run into this beautiful lady, whose skin gleams in the sun light."
```

So the outcome I'd expect would be something like:

```
beautiful: 2
day: 1
neighborhood: 1
sun: 2
```

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
results = {}
for i in firstfile:
        results[i] = secondfile.count(i) 
print(results)
```

but it prints out something like

```
{'beautiful': 0, 'day': 0, 'neighborhood': 0, 'sun': 0}
```

which is obviously incorrect.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with a dozen of different approaches but none of them seem to return anything other than 0 for the overlapping words. Is there something wrong with the code, or should I go about creating the lists from firstfile.txt and secondfile.txt in a specific way? Thanks, everyone! (Also, I'm a complete newbie to Python (and programming in general), so please forgive me if this is a stupid question or if I'm not putting things clearly!!)

Comment: In your post, `secondfile` is not a list but a single string, which is also the reason why your code only produces 0 matches.

Comment: what about if I've converted secondfile into a list? it looks like ['It's', 'a', 'beautiful', 'day', 'in', 'the', 'neighborhood', 'today'] etc. It still returns 0 matches

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare firstfile as a list:

```
firstfile = ['beautiful', 'day', 'neighborhood', 'sun']

secondfile = "It's a beautiful day in the neighborhood today. The sun is shining brightly, and the birds are singing. And now I run into this beautiful lady, whose skin gleams in the sun light."

results = {}

for i in firstfile:
    results[i] = secondfile.count(i)
```

This works for me.

Comment: thanks! what about if my files are thousands of hundreds words long and I can't fit them into a compact list like that in the code? (hope that makes sense!)

Comment: read them in using a context manger and readlines(). Like this: with open(path) as f: firstfile  = f.readlines(). This returns a list with newline characters. Use f.read() to read the entire text as a string.

Comment: okay, so now my files look something like this:

firstfile:
'beautiful',
'day',
'neighborhood',
'sun',
etc.

secondfile:
'It's',
'a',
'beautiful',
'day',
'in',
'the',
'neighborhood',
etc.
(all words in new lines)

But now print(results) just returns this:
{}

jesus christ

Comment: Use firstfile.split(",") to get a list then text = "".join(secondfile).replace(",", "") to get a string.